# Gaps in border around text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to add a border around some texts in a matplotlib plot, which I can do using `patheffects.withStroke`. However, for some letters and number there is a small gap to the top right of the symbol.

Is there a way to not have this gap?

Minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as patheffects

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(
    0.1, 0.5, "test: S6",
    color='white',
    fontsize=90,
    path_effects=[patheffects.withStroke(linewidth=13, foreground='black')])
fig.savefig("text_stroke.png")
```

This gives the image, which shows the gap in S and 6 symbols.
[image]

I'm using matplotlib 1.5.1.

Comment: I think this is intended. The contour of the letters is drawn like with a shaped brush, leaving the start and arriving at the end point at a different angle, hence the misconnection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation does not mention it (or I did not found it) but, searching in the code, we can see that the `patheffects.withStroke` method accepts a lot of keyword arguments.

You can have the list of those keyword arguments by executing this in interactive session:

```
>>> from matplotlib.backend_bases import GraphicsContextBase as gcb
>>> print([attr[4:] for attr in dir(gcb) if attr.startswith("set_")])
['alpha', 'antialiased', 'capstyle', 'clip_path', 'clip_rectangle', 'dashes', 'foreground', 'gid', 'graylevel', 'hatch', 'joinstyle', 'linestyle', 'linewidth', 'sketch_params', 'snap', 'url']
```

The argument you are looking for is `capstyle` which accepts 3 possible values:

- "butt"
- "round"
- "projecting"

In you case, the "round" value seems to fix the problem.
Consider the code below...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as patheffects

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(
    0.1, 0.5, "test: S6",
    color='white',
    fontsize=90,
    path_effects=[patheffects.withStroke(linewidth=13, foreground='black', capstyle="round")])
fig.savefig("text_stroke.png")
```

... it produces this:

[image]

---

The accepted keywords arguments are actually all the `set_*` (minus the "set_" prefixe) methods of the [GraphicsContextBase](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.GraphicsContextBase) class. You can find details on the accepted values into the class documentation.

Comment: That worked nicely, thanks! I'm guessing this should be better documented somewhere, possibly in the doc-string. I'll make an Issue on the GitHub matplotlib repository.